# Typescript: The return type of a function to be the type of one property from multiple types

Tags: typescript

```
declare type Foo = {
  fieldA?: 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
  fieldB?: SomeOtherType;
  fieldC?: number;
  fieldD?: string;
  fieldE?: boolean;
}

declare type Bar = {
  fieldX?: boolean;
  fieldY?: 'hello' | 'world'
  fieldZ?: AndYetAnotherType;
}

const getPropertyFromFooOrBar = (
  property: string,
  foo: Foo,
  bar: Bar
): MISSING_TYPE => {
  return foo[property] || bar[property] || undefined;
};
```

I need the return type of the function (`MISSING_TYPE` above) to be a value from `Foo` or `Bar` (or `undefined`). Is there something similar to `keyof Bar` that can be used to handle this typing?

Comment: Although there might be a solution to your problem out there, I'm wondering why you have to do such an intricate thing.

Comment: Doesn't seem that intricate to me. It's just trying to combine all the possible values from the two types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the type of a property of combined types by creating a union type and using keyof that union type in a generic type declaration.  That's a confusing sentence - here are the steps taken in the example below:

- First, an union type called *FooAndBar* is declared.  This isn't necessary, but it makes things more readable.
- A generic type argument is created for the function that derives from the keys of the intersection type.
- The property argument is declared using that generic type.
- In order to avoid a compiler issue, the two objects are combined.  This way they fit the signature of the *FooAndBar* type.
- Because the types are combined, I can use the value of property in an indexer.  Either the value will be fined in the combined type or undefined will be returned.
- The return type of the sample call will be *'a' | 'b' | 'c'* since the language service picks up that *fieldA* is a property of *Foo* with *'a' | 'b' | 'c'* as its type.

```
type FooAndBar = Foo & Bar;

const getPropertyFromFooOrBar = <T extends keyof FooAndBar>(
  property: T,
  foo: Foo,
  bar: Bar
): FooAndBar[T] | undefined => {
  return { ...foo, ... bar }[property];
};

getPropertyFromFooOrBar('fieldA', { fieldA: 'a' }, { fieldY: 'hello' });
// getPropertyFromFooOrBar: <"fieldA">(property: "fieldA", foo: Foo, bar: Bar) => "a" | "b" | "c"
```

Comment: Thank you such a detailed and clear response!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with the following:

```
declare type Foo = {
  fieldA?: 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
  fieldB?: SomeOtherType;
  fieldC?: number;
  fieldD?: string;
  fieldE?: boolean;
}

declare type Bar = {
  fieldX?: boolean;
  fieldY?: 'hello' | 'world'
  fieldZ?: AndYetAnotherType;
}

type FooValue = Foo[keyof Foo];
type BarValue = Bar[keyof Bar];

const getPropertyFromFooOrBar = (
  property: string,
  foo: Foo,
  bar: Bar
): FooValue | BarValue | undefined => {
  return foo[property] || bar[property] || undefined;
};
```